# Android API 26 Platform not found, package not available for download

Tags: android, android-studio, build.gradle

[image: Error image.]This occurred after I upgraded my android studio. I've attempted all similar answers on stack overflow, and a few other obscure forums, but I'm not getting anywhere with this error and I've been at it for 6 hours. I've monkeyed around with the sdk tools manager as well, but I'm not getting anywhere. Oh, and that maven thing is new, tried it from a similar answer.

Here is my gradle file:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.loredylore.lorebuilder"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0-alpha1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.0.0-alpha1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.0.0-alpha1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:26.0.0-alpha1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.0.0-alpha1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:11.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:11.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:26.0.0-alpha1'
    //new
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
}

// Add to the bottom of the file
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: The picture you posted is unreadable. Does this happen if you do file -> new project? What if you add dependencies 1 by 1? Did you try a clean-rebuild? What is “the latest” android studio that you installed? Do you have the SDK files for Platform 26? Did you delete / re-download all the SDK (just in case it’s broken?) I mean, it’s hard to tell what’s going on. Try with API 25, do you have the same problem?

Comment: avoiding the file new project at all cost, too much to reconfigure. It's version 2 of Platform 26 though. I do have the sdk files, downloaded and installed android studio and the sdk again in a new directory and changed the path to that new sdk directory, but the same behavior/errors appear. I'm trying the API 25 route right now, but now I have to fix a bunch of new dependency issues. Clean-rebuild was one of the first things I tried.Not sure why the image is so small, but if you scroll-wheel it in and hold the control button, then it should be visible/clear if you're on windows.

Comment: The very least you could do is crop the image to make it a viewable size. The better option would be to copy/paste the information as text.

Comment: didn't give me the image to resize the image as I didn't have enough rep, not really something one can copy and paste either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use version 25.0.3, you may have to recast some views to text views when if you have to migrate backward from version 26 android to 25.